# C++ dynamic expanding array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

In C++ can you allocate an array without telling it how big the array is going to be?  I am simulating a grocery checkout program and I was going to use a multidimensional to achieve this because the input needs to be as following:
"Please enter product number and quantity" 110111 4 (first is product number, second is quantity).

This below throws an error because of the second value

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "checkout.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Checkout check;
    int choice;
    int array_size = 0;
    int max = 10;
    int* product_info = new int[max][1];

    do{
        cout << "Please Enter Item Number and Quantity: ";
        cin >> product_info[array_size][array_size];
    }while(!choice == 0);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT *** I realize the array cin is messed up in this example.

Comment: Use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. And go grab a book on C++ - this is not an easy language and you better don't try to learn with experiments only.

Comment: Do use `vector`, but take the time to learn the alternative as well.

Comment: I am in a C++ Class, which this is for, Rafal but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A two dimensional array does not appear to be very efficient for this task, the array would be very sparse.

You could dynamically grow it as needed, but only in one dimension (that you can choose as coding time), the other one would have to be permanently fixed, which is at best a half solution.

In your program you use one dimension that is declared to have bound `1`.  This means that allowed indexes would range only from `0` to `0` and thus that dimension would not really exist.

So you simply need something like a one dimensional array (indexed by product ID; the quantity will be placed *inside* the array rather than as a second dimension to it); and in your application, a `vector` in place of the array (as indicated in comments) will handle the dynamic aspects (reallocation) for you so that you will not even have to care how big the vector is at the moment.

The following is how you can declare the structure, except that the POS code (the ID of the item) would normally be too large to fit into an `int` in a real application, and the quantity might not always be genuinely integral.

```
struct transaction_line
{
    int poscode;
    int quantity;
};

std::vector<transaction_line> transaction;
```

Comment: So your saying it only can grow in one dimension.  So the alternative would be using vector like the people above said, or create two one dimension arrays

Comment: @chad or a vector of vectors.

Comment: Originally downvoted (but now removed the downvote) because your intention was not clear. When you add the transaction_line structure it becomes reasonable.

Comment: @ViktorLatypov - I'm returning the temporary favor ;-) until your sample code starts handling repeated scanning of the same item correctly ( = in a way that I understand).  With respect and enjoyment.

Comment: Ok, it's too late - next time I read the task more carefully :))) Cheers :)))